# How can i save my icon with 8 bit 32 bit color

Tags: icon

Please any one can tell me how to save my icon which made by AI and apen it in the work area in PS to save it but i cant save it with 32 bit color this is the pic which i should do like they say [image]

Answer (score 1):

That info is misleading.

Basicly you can save a PNG file which have 8 bits per channel, plus a transparency channel.

**RGB=24 + Transparency = 32**